# Automatically refresh a grid when data changes and query is no longer satisfied

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I have a store with data `{ name: String, enabled: Boolean }`. When I display the dgrid, I set the query as `{ enabled: true }` so that I effectively filter out all "disabled" entries. I actually have three grid displaying the same store. They all get the notify, no worries.

If I edit a field, and save it with `{enabled: false}`, I need to refresh the dgrid because the query conditions for that entry are no longer satisfied (the `enabled` field has changed). The notify only makes sure that the cell itself is updated -- the fact that it no longer satisfies a query condition is not considered.

So, my question: what should I do in this case? I could issue a refresh for the grid manually, but then again the other 2 grids will need to be refreshed too.

What's the best way to go about it? Am I missing something completely obvious?

Thank you!

Merc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to add a comment, but based on your description, your store doesn't seem to notify the grid of the changes (read-only store?). What store are you using?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store.html

Another reason could be that you are using the deprecated dojo/data API based store (eg: dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore), and dgrid doesn't support it's notifications.

http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/grids_and_stores/

Comment: Nope, using a normal store, not read-only, and I am using the latest Store API. Are dgrids supposed to actually re-apply the query filter after changing an element...?

Comment: As per the docs, the notifications should be tied to the query and hence should work fine.  

"The grid itself knows nothing (and should know nothing) of how queries work, and so it can’t filter these events. By putting notifications on the query action itself, notifications can be stated in terms of how they affect a given query result set, which is what the widget ultimately cares about." 

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store.html#notification-rational

Comment: In the end, it was my cstom Observable.js that was misbehaving, but your answer gave me the lead :D Thank you!